# javadoc upgrade from 6 to 7

Tags: java, ubuntu, upgrade, javadoc

When generating javadoc I get an error when javadoc is parsing the diamond operator es:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>()
// javadoc 6 blocks here
```

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and the command `javadoc -J-version` says I am using:

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
```

However I have compiled and developed the project in Java 7. Of course if I type

```
java -version
```

I have the following result: `java version "1.7.0_21"`

How can I change/upgrade the jdk used by the javadoc command?

**UDPATE**: This is what I get with update-java alternatives

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386
```

I do not even get java 1.7.0 which is the one I am using. Again java -version returns java 1.7.0.

Comment: You seem to have your java versions linked wrong - try using [update-java-alternatives](http://askubuntu.com/a/141798) to set all the java related alternatives.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have selected the right java version 1.7.0.. still javadoc seems to be set in java 6

Comment: You say `java -version` returns version 7. What about `javadoc -version`? You haven't linked _all_ the Java alternatives.

Comment: javadoc -J-version returns java 1.6 and java -version returns java 1.7

Comment: As I said in my first comment, you have not selected the right java version. Read the link.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have updated my question. I don't even get to choose java 7 while following the instruction of your link.. How can I do to fix it?  Thanks